# Django, How show image in admin penal?

Tags: django-models

I try to show image in admin list but can't find how to do it. Here is my code

```
def photos_thumb( self ):
    return format_html( '<img src="%s"/>' % self.photo )
```

This code shows only an image save path like this < uploads/2017/10/20/imagename.jpg >
Any ideas pls?

Comment: Admin list ? you mean the admin site ? post the full view and give more inside about your question so we can help you.

Comment: I got solution after try to google around. Thank for reply :)